# Two if conditions and explode

Tags: php

I have this working function:

```
function pingAddress($ip) {
    $lines = file('F:\share\result.txt');
    foreach($lines as $line){
        $parts = explode(' ', $line);
        if($parts[0] == $ip){
            return $parts[1];
        }
    }
}

echo pingAddress('192.168.50.105'); // UP
```

It returns UP or DOWN from a file looking like this:

```
192.168.50.104 UP
192.168.50.105 UP
192.168.50.106 DOWN
192.168.50.107 UP
```

I can't add a background color to display with UP or DOWN.
Something like:

```
function pingAddress($ip) {
    $lines = file('F:\share\result.txt');
    foreach($lines as $line){
        $parts = explode(' ', $line);
        if($parts[0] == $ip && $parts[1] == 'UP'){
            echo "<p style='background-color:lime'>";
            return $parts[1];
        }else{
            echo "<p style='background-color:red'>";
            return $parts[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `file()` by default leaves the new line on the end of the string, so when you try and compare it to `UP` - it won't match as it's `UP` with a new line.

Either use

```
$lines = file('F:\share\result.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

to remove the new lines or trim the output

```
if($parts[0] == $ip && trim($parts[1]) == 'UP'){
```

Is also depends if you are going to have multiple entries in the file for the same IP address, some may be up and some down.  You would need to cater for this if it may happen.

You will also need to add the colour formatting to where you output the data, this only currently returns the data.